# JS счетчик и смена блока

Tags: javascript, счетчики, countdown

Здравствуйте!
у меня есть 2 странички, одна с отсчетом времени (стоит счетчик), другая с контентом. Мне нужно чтобы страничка с СЧЕТЧИКОМ, КАЖДЫЙ ДЕНЬ переключалась на страничку с контентом (редирект)  в определенное время, например в 17.00, работала (то есть была доступна), например 5 часов, а потом снова переключалась назад (то есть в 22.00) на стр. с счетчиком
счетчик взял отсюда https://webformyself.com/tajmer-obratnogo-otscheta-dlya-sajta

Пробовал сделать без редиректа, сделал из 2 страниц 2 блока и с помощью jQuery.load() хотел подгружать определенный блок, но не работает(

Прошу подсказки/помощи в решение этой задачки

Спасибо

```
  var myDate,

      startTime_Hours = 21, // начало - часы
      startTime_Min = 57, // начало - минуты
      startTime_Sec = 0, // начало - секунды

      EndTimeHours = 21, // конец - часы
      EndTimeMin = 58; // конец - минуты
      EndTimeSec = 0; // конец - секунды

  var commonDate = new Date(), 
  countdownShow,
  todayMill = commonDate.getTime(),
  todayMillStartPoint = commonDate.setHours(startTime_Hours, startTime_Min, startTime_Sec),
  todayMillEndPoint = commonDate.setHours(EndTimeHours,EndTimeMin, EndTimeSec),
  yesterday = commonDate.setDate(commonDate.getDate()-2);

  var tomorrow = new Date();

  if (tomorrow.getTime() > tomorrow.setHours(startTime_Hours, startTime_Min, startTime_Sec)) {
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  } else {
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate());
  }
  tomorrow.setHours(startTime_Hours, startTime_Min, startTime_Sec);

  if (todayMill >= todayMillStartPoint && todayMill <= todayMillEndPoint) {
    myDate = new Date(yesterday);
  } else {
    myDate = tomorrow;
  }

if (countdownShow) {
    $('#common-wrap').load("countdown.html")
} else {
    $('#common-wrap').load("content.html")
}

function get_timer() {

//Дата для обратного отсчета
// var date_new = dateEnd;
var date_new = myDate;
////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////

//Объект даты для обратного отсчета
var date_t = new Date(date_new);
//Объект текущей даты
var date = new Date();
//Вычесляем сколько миллисекунд пройдет 
//от текущей даты до даты отсчета времени
var timer = date_t - date;

//Проверяем не нужно ли закончить отсчет
//если дата отсчета еще не истекла, то количество
//миллисекунд в переменной date_t будет больше чем в переменной date
if(date_t > date) {
    //Вычисляем сколько осталось дней до даты отсчета.
    //Для этого количество миллисекунд до даты остчета делим
    //на количество миллисекунд в одном дне
    var day = parseInt(timer/(60*60*1000*24));
    //если полученное число меньше 10 прибавляем 0
    if(day < 10) {
        day = '0' + day;
    }
    //Приводим результат к строке
    day = day.toString();

    //Вычисляем сколько осталось часов до даты отсчета.
    //Для этого переменную timer делим на количество
    //миллисекунд в одном часе и отбрасываем дни
    var hour = parseInt(timer/(60*60*1000))%24;
    //если полученное число меньше 10 прибавляем 0
    if(hour < 10) {
        hour = '0' + hour;
    }
    //Приводим результат к строке
    hour = hour.toString();

    //Вычисляем сколько осталось минут до даты отсчета.
    //Для этого переменную timer делим на количество
    //миллисекунд в одной минуте и отбрасываем часы
    var min = parseInt(timer/(1000*60))%60;
    //если полученное число меньше 10 прибавляем 0
    if(min < 10) {
        min = '0' + min;
    }
    //Приводим результат к строке
    min = min.toString();

    //Вычисляем сколько осталось секунд до даты отсчета.
    //Для этого переменную timer делим на количество
    //миллисекунд в одной минуте и отбрасываем минуты
    var sec = parseInt(timer/1000)%60;
    //если полученное число меньше 10 прибавляем 0
    if(sec < 10) {
        sec = '0' + sec;
    }
    //Приводим результат к строке
    sec = sec.toString();

    //Выводим дни
    //Проверяем какие предыдущие цифры времени должны вывестись на экран
    //Для десятков дней
    if(day[1] == 9 && 
        hour[0] == 2 && 
        hour[1] == 3 && 
        min[0] == 5 && 
        min[1] == 9 && 
        sec[0] == 5 && 
        sec[1] == 9) {
        animation($("#day0"),day[0]);
        animation($("#second-day0"),day[0]);
        animation($("#third-day0"),day[0]);
    }
    else {
        $("#day0").html(day[0]);
        $("#second-day0").html(day[0]);
        $("#third-day0").html(day[0]);
    }
    //Для единиц дней
    if(hour[0] == 2 && 
        hour[1] == 3 && 
        min[0] == 5 && 
        min[1] == 9 && 
        sec[0] == 5 && 
        sec[1] == 9) {
        animation($("#day1"),day[1]);
        animation($("#second-day1"),day[1]);
        animation($("#third-day1"),day[1]);
    }
    else {
        $("#day1").html(day[1]);
        $("#second-day1").html(day[1]);
        $("#third-day1").html(day[1]);
    }
    //Выводим часы
    //Проверяем какие предыдущие цифры времени должны вывестись на экран
    //Для десятков часов
    if(hour[1] == 3 && 
        min[0] == 5 && 
        min[1] == 9 && 
        sec[0] == 5 && 
        sec[1] == 9) {
        animation($("#hour0"),hour[0]);
        animation($("#second-hour0"),hour[0]);
        animation($("#third-hour0"),hour[0]);
    }
    else {
        $("#hour0").html(hour[0]);
        $("#second-hour0").html(hour[0]);
        $("#third-hour0").html(hour[0]);
    }
    //Для единиц чассов 
    if(min[0] == 5 && 
        min[1] == 9 && 
        sec[0] == 5 && 
        sec[1] == 9) {
        animation($("#hour1"),hour[1]);
        animation($("#second-hour1"),hour[1]);
        animation($("#third-hour1"),hour[1]);
    }
    else {
        $("#hour1").html(hour[1]);
        $("#second-hour1").html(hour[1]);
        $("#third-hour1").html(hour[1]);
    }

    //Выводим минуты
    //Проверяем какие предыдущие цифры времени должны вывестись на экран
    //Для десятков минут
    if(min[1] == 9 && 
        sec[0] == 5 && 
        sec[1] == 9) {
        animation($("#min0"),min[0]);
        animation($("#second-min0"),min[0]);
        animation($("#third-min0"),min[0]);
    }
    else {
        $("#min0").html(min[0]);
        $("#second-min0").html(min[0]);
        $("#third-min0").html(min[0]);
    }
    //Для единиц минут
    if(sec[0] == 5 && sec[1] == 9) {
        animation($("#min1"),min[1]);
        animation($("#second-min1"),min[1]);
        animation($("#third-min1"),min[1]);
    }
    else {
        $("#min1").html(min[1]);
        $("#second-min1").html(min[1]);
        $("#third-min1").html(min[1]);
    }

    //Выводим секунды
    //Проверяем какие предыдущие цифры времени должны вывестись на экран
    //Для десятков секунд
    if(sec[1] == 9) {
        animation($("#sec0"),sec[0]);
        animation($("#second-sec0"),sec[0]);
        animation($("#third-sec0"),sec[0]);
    }
    else {
        $("#sec0").html(sec[0]);
        $("#second-sec0").html(sec[0]);
        $("#third-sec0").html(sec[0]);
    }
    animation($("#sec1"),sec[1]);   
    animation($("#second-sec1"),sec[1]);    
    animation($("#third-sec1"),sec[1]); 
    //Переодически вызываем созданную функцию, 
    //интервал вызова одна секунда(1000 милли секунд)
    setTimeout(get_timer,1000);
    countdownShow = true;
}
else {
    countdownShow = false
}
}
```

Comment: Код, где код, Карл? Что вы УЖЕ сделали? Что у вас не получается сделать сейчас? Больше конкретики, пожалуйста. :)

Comment: сорри, сверху добавил код

Comment: @Mit9I а вот теперь ждём гуру JS. Я лишь призвал вас облегчить им поиск ответа на ваш вопрос, а остальное за ними. :)

Comment: ок, будем ждать)

Comment: напишу чуть по-другому, есть 2 блока, как мне, основываясь на таймере, скрывать один блок и показывать другой и так каждый раз, то есть зациклить функционал? Все идеи исчерпал....подскажите плз кто нибудь)

Comment: If ( !(time>17 && time<22)) { $('.block).toggle(); }

Comment: Так 2 страницы иди два блока на одной страницы? Переключаться дороже должно в момент загрузки страницы или изменения времени? Почему не сделать переадресацию на бэкэнде?

Comment: с начало было на разных страницах, был редирект, а сейчас я сделал все на одной странице, так как мне показалось это более простым решением. Переключаться должно в режиме реального времени, то есть счетчик отсчитал своё, блок_1 автоматом исчез, блок_2 появился, прошел какой-то интервал времени блок_2 исчез, блок_1 появился и так постоянно...Переключение при загрузке страницы  -  такой вариант у меня работает, но не устраивает( надо в режиме реального времени

Comment: делал функцию которая отслеживала переменную countdownShow с интервалом в 1сек и соответственно ДОЛЖНА была подгружать нужный блок, но опять же подгрузка блока у меня идет через jquery.load() и получается, что load() подгружает блок каждые 1сек))

Comment: бэкэнда нету, только фронт

Comment: написал функцию `function blockRedirect() {
       // добавляем 99 миллисекунд, чтобы точно и 1 ТОЛЬКО РАЗ сработало условие в период этого времени
       if (new Date().getTime() >= todayMillEndPoint && new Date().getTime() <= todayMillEndPoint+99) { 
        window.location.reload(true);
       }
       setTimeout(blockRedirect, 100)
      }
      blockRedirect()`    но мне кажется такая конструкция не надежная, может кто-то подскажет вариант по-лучше? буду благодарен